# How to call a ruby block to get access to the caller bindings

Tags: ruby, binding, scope, block

I want to have access to the bindings of the caller. What's wrong here?

```
require 'test/unit'

class BlocksTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  class Blocks
    def initialize( &block ); @block = block; end
    def run; instance_eval { @block.call }; end

    def foo; 'foo'; end
  end

  def test_say_foo_via_string
    assert_equal( 'foo', Blocks.new{ 'foo' }.run )
  end
  # => successful

  def test_say_foo_via_caller_method
    assert_equal( 'foo', Blocks.new{ foo }.run )
  end
  # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'

end
```

Why i don't have access to the caller instance within the given block?

Comment: Dear Downvoter! I'm relatively new here and it would be nice getting some advices if my question is not useful. :-) I changed the question code to a complete test class `BlocksTest`. I also changed the block call in the `run` method from `@block.call` to `instance_eval { @block.call }` which raises the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the block you are not in the scope of the `Blocks` instance, so `foo` is not visible. You have to pass the object to the block if you want to have access to it:

```
class Blocks
  # ...
  def run
    @block.call(self)
  end
  # ...
end

blk = Blocks.new { |b| b.foo }
blk.run
# => "foo"
```

Alternatively you can pass the block to `instance_eval`:

```
class Blocks
  # ...
  def run
    instance_eval(&@block)
  end
  # ...
end

blk = Blocks.new { foo }
blk.run
# => "foo"
```

Comment: For the difference between a proc and a block see [this](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) and [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-on-rails-study-guide-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried the second solution before i asked the question but without the `&` operator. `instance_eval { @block.call };` raises the same error. What's the difference between the block and the Proc syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I didn't found an explanation for the difference between `instance_eval( &block )` and `instance_eval { block.call }`. The first way converts the Proc to a block and the second creates a new block and executes the Proc. I have still no idea why the bindings/scopes of the approaches differ. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce it :

```
3.times.map{ foo }
#~>  undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Inside `{ }` or outside of `{}`, `foo` has not been defined as a `method` or `varable`. Thus Ruby parser got confused and throws error.

Now see:

```
foo = 12
3.times.map{ foo }
# => [12, 12, 12]
```

Try :

```
test "say method_foo" do
  assert_equal( 'foo', Blocks.new{|i| i.foo }.run )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Blocks
  def initialize( &block ); @block = block; end
  def run; instance_eval &@block; end

  def foo; 'foo'; end
end
```